# Minus or not equal to? Which is better?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with 3 columns cost, from_date and to_date. I have to select all the rows which do not have the dates from beginning of the month to the end of the month. That is, select rows which do not have the from_date as '1-NOV-2011' and to_date as '30-NOV-2011'. I've written 2 queries.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE FROM_DATE <> '1-NOV-2011' OR TO_DATE <> '30-NOV-2011';
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 MINUS SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE FROM_DATE = '1-NOV-2011' AND TO_DATE = '30-NOV-2011';
```

Which one will give a better performance?

Comment: Have you tried it? If not, why not?

Comment: I did try it. The second one was a little bit faster. But I'm not sure if its due to the difference in load on the server(Lots of people are using the server).

Comment: The logic in your first query is wrong: it should be `AND`, not `OR`. Using `OR` will return all rows that either don't start at the beginning of November or don't finish at the end of November, which is different to (but includes) the rows that run only for the duration of November.

Comment: What does the query plan tell you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st one is better, since that involves only a single scan also that does not contains any 'in's or 'not in's. go for 1st first one...

Answer (score 1):

## Clarification

First off, the two queries are not equivalent. The following sets would produce the same results:

### Set 1

#### Query 1

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE NOT (FROM_DATE = '1-NOV-2011' AND TO_DATE = '30-NOV-2011');
```

#### Query 2

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
MINUS SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
      WHERE FROM_DATE = '1-NOV-2011' AND TO_DATE = '30-NOV-2011';
```

### Set 2

#### Query 1

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
WHERE FROM_DATE <> '1-NOV-2011' OR TO_DATE <> '30-NOV-2011';
```

### Query 2

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
MINUS SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
      WHERE FROM_DATE = '1-NOV-2011' OR TO_DATE = '30-NOV-2011';
```

---

## Answer

Now to the actual answer. The prima facie answer is that the first query (for either set) will be faster, because it involves only one table access, rather than two. However, that may not be true.

It's possible that the second query will be faster. In the first, the database will need to do a full-table scan, then check each row for the disqualifying values. In the second case, it can do a full table scan without a filter to fulfill the first half off the query. For the second half, if there is an index on `FROM_DATE` and `TO_DATE`, it can use an index scan to get the disqualifying rows then perform a set operation to remove those results from the first set.

Whether this is actually faster or not will likely depend a lot on your data. As always, the best way to determine which will be faster for your application is to perform your own benchmarks.

Comment: What wll be the output of the 2 queries in set 2 if the table is like this:
`1 '1-NOV-2011' '30-NOV-2011'`
`2 '2-NOV-2011' '30-NOV-2011'`
`3 '1-NOV-2011' '29-NOV-2011'`
`4 '2-NOV-2011' '29-NOV-2011'`

Answer (score 0):

I guess, 1st version will have better performance than 2nd version.

`SELECT` is happening twice in 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

The second one will definitely be slower.  You're basically pulling two sets in the second one and doing a set difference.  Only the smaller set can be pulled with an index (assuming you have indexes, and assuming doesn't do some magical optimization).  The first query builds just one set and it is based on indexes.

Disclaimer: That's a simplified explanation, and I know nothing of the inner workings of Oracle, just how I would expect it to work.